# Timeline control

Tags: c#, controls

I need a control something like this:

http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/1411/timeline.jpg

It is used for time selection.

I can add several horizontal time lines. I can add/edit/delete time intervals on every time line (programmatically). I can change time scale etc...

I think you guess general meaning ...

It must be free.

Answer (score 1):

I use timeline from [simile-widgets](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) (JavaScript + XML).

[Live demo from my site.](http://msug.vn.ua/timeline.html)

**Update.**
[C# / Silverlight Timeline controls on codeplex.](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=timeline)